# A ServerTrustEvaluating value is required for host "my.host.be" but none was found

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a `WebService` which holds a `Session`

```swift
self.session = Session(
    configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default,
    serverTrustManager: ServerTrustManager(evaluators: ["my.hostname.be": PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator()]))
```

When I then send a request to `https://my.hostname.be/some/strange/route`, I receive the error `A ServerTrustEvaluating value is required for host "my.hostname.be" but none was found.`

Am I forgetting something?

When I check in the `self.session.serverTrustManager.evaluators`, I can see the key `"my.hostname.be"` so the evaluator is registered and it has a `PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator`.

Comment: Have you added your server's ssl certificate in your app's target?

Comment: Yes, there is only one certificate

Comment: however, I see that the common name of the certificate is `*.hostname.be`. But that should not give any problems, right?

Comment: No, is shouldn't. But the error mentions another host `my.host.be`.

Comment: sorry that was a typo, the hostnames are equal

Comment: Are you using this `Session` instance to make your network calls?

Comment: yes, and when I place a breakpoint at `session.request(url)`, I can see the evaluators dictionary with the entry of `"my.hostname.be"`

Comment: Never mind, the issue was at serverside... Thanks for the help